# chrome with linux

Tags: google-chrome, package-management, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm a bit of a Linux noob. I'm on a brand new desktop running RedHat and just trying to get Chrome going. Following a guide, I was told to download the .deb file, then to run sudo dpkg on that deb file. The error I get is the following:

dpkg: command not found

Is there some kind of problem with my PATH? What do people mean when they say that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm -i package_name.rpm` will install Chrome.

It will install too the google repository.
To get an update, you'll have to type, as root, `yum update`.
It will update your system and your browser.

Comment: Just wondering - what is the -i indicate? and would you happen to know what I should do for Chrome if I run into failed dependencies when running rpm? It says it needs lsb >= 4.0

Comment: `-i` to indicate you want to install it. Try `yum install lsb`. It will install it with all dependancies required. After that, re-try the `rmp` command.

Answer (score 3):

Red Hat isn't Debian based, so a .deb file won't do you a whole lot of good.  You want the .rpm-based install.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` and .deb files are specific to Debian-based distros (e.g. Ubuntu). Redhat uses `rpm`, so you should get the .rpm file instead, and install it like so:

```
rpm -i chrome.rpm
```

Where `chrome.rpm` is the name of the file.